# Python Lambda actioning CSV file once but not the second time

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jsonschema

I am experiencing a strange issue with my Python code. It's objective is the following:

- Retrieve a .csv from S3
- Convert that .csv into JSON (Its an array of objects)
- Add a few key value pairs to each object in the Array, and change the original key values
- Validate the JSON
- Sent the JSON to a /output S3 bucket
- Load the JSON into Dynamo

Here's what the .csv looks like:

```
Prefix,Provider
ABCDE,Provider A
QWERT,Provider B
ASDFG,Provider C
ZXCVB,Provider D
POIUY,Provider E
```

And here's my python script:

```
import json
import boto3
import ast
import csv
import os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import jsonschema 
from jsonschema import validate

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
providerCodesSchema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",    
      "properties": {
          "providerCode": {"type": "string", "maxLength": 5},
          "providerName": {"type": "string"},
          "activeFrom": {"type": "string", "format": "date"},
          "activeTo": {"type": "string"},
          "apiActiveFrom": {"type": "string"},
          "apiActiveTo": {"type": "string"},
          "countThreshold": {"type": "string"}
      },
      "required": ["providerCode", "providerName"]
    }
}

datestamp = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
timestamp = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%s")
updateTime = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S")
nowdatetime = dt.datetime.now()
yesterday = nowdatetime - dt.timedelta(days=1)
nintydaysfromnow = nowdatetime + dt.timedelta(days=90)

def lambda_handler(event, context):


filename_json = "/tmp/file_{ts}.json".format(ts=timestamp)
filename_csv = "/tmp/file_{ts}.csv".format(ts=timestamp)
keyname_s3 = "newloader-ptv/output/{ds}/{ts}.json".format(ds=datestamp, ts=timestamp)
json_data = []

for record in event['Records']:
    bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key_name = record['s3']['object']['key']

s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
data = s3_object['Body'].read()
contents = data.decode('latin')

with open(filename_csv, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_data:
    csv_data.write(contents)

with open(filename_csv, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_data:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_data)
    for csv_row in csv_reader:
        json_data.append(csv_row)
    for elem in json_data:
        elem['providerCode'] = elem.pop('Prefix')
        elem['providerName'] = elem.pop('Provider')
    for element in json_data:
        element['activeFrom'] = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00-00:00")
        element['activeTo'] = nintydaysfromnow.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00-00:00")
        element['apiActiveFrom'] = " "
        element['apiActiveTo'] = " "
        element['countThreshold'] = "3"
        element['updateDate'] = updateTime


    try:
       validate(instance=json_data, schema=providerCodesSchema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        print(err)
        err = "Given JSON data is InValid"
        return None


with open(filename_json, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps(json_data, default=str))

with open(filename_json, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file_contents:
    response = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=keyname_s3, Body=json_file_contents.read())

for jsonElement in json_data:
    table = dynamodb.Table('privateProviders-loader')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonElement)
    print("finished enriching JSON")

os.remove(filename_csv)
os.remove(filename_json)

return None
```

I'm new to Python, so please forgive any amateur mistakes in the code.

Here's my issue:
When I deploy the code, and add a valid .csv into my S3 bucket, everything works.
When I then add an invalid .csv into my S3 buck, again it work, the import fails as the validation kicks in and tells me the problem.
However, when I add the valid .csv back into the S3 bucket, I get the same cloudwatch log as I did for the invalid .csv, and my Dynamo isn't updated, nor is an output JSON file sent to /output in S3.

With some troubleshooting I've noticed the following behavour:

- When I first deploy the code, the first .csv loads as expected (dynamo table updated + JSON file sent to S3 + cloudwatch logs documenting the process)
- If I enter the same valid .csv into the S3 bucket, it gives me the same nice looking cloudwatch logs, but none of the other actions take place (Dynamo not updated etc)
- If I add the invalid .csv, that seems to break the cycle, and I get a nice Cloudwatch log showing the validation has kicked in, but if I reload the valid .csv, which just previously resulted in good cloudwatch logs (but no actual real outputs), I now get a repeat of the validation error log.

In short, the first time the function is invoked, it seems to work, the second time it doesn't.

It seems as though the python function is caching something or not closing out the function when finished, and I've played about with the return command etc, but nothing I've tried works. I've sunk many hours into trying to move parts of the code around etc. thinking the structure or order of events is the problem, and I've the code above gives me the closest behaviour to expected, given that it seems to work completely the first and only time I load the .csv into S3.

Any help or general pointers would be massively appreciated.

Thanks
P.s. Here's an example of the Cloudwatch log when validation kicks in a and stops an invalid .csv from being processed. If I then add a valid .csv to S£, the function is triggered, but I get this same error, even though the file is actually good.

```
2021-06-29T22:12:27.709+01:00   'ABCDEE' is too long
2021-06-29T22:12:27.709+01:00   Failed validating 'maxLength' in schema['items']['properties']['providerCode']:
2021-06-29T22:12:27.709+01:00   {'maxLength': 5, 'type': 'string'}
2021-06-29T22:12:27.709+01:00   On instance[2]['providerCode']:
2021-06-29T22:12:27.709+01:00   'ABCDEE'
2021-06-29T22:12:27.710+01:00   END RequestId: 81dd6a2d-130b-4c8f-ad08-39307841adf9
2021-06-29T22:12:27.710+01:00   REPORT RequestId: 81dd6a2d-130b-4c8f-ad08-39307841adf9 Duration: 482.43 ms Billed Duration: 483
```

Comment: A few questions... Is the formatting of your code correct, or should code be indented in the `lambda_handler()`? Why is the code writing and then reading `filename_json` -- could it just use `put_object(...,Body=json.dumps(json_data))` rather than sending it via a file? Why is it **appending** in `open(filename_csv, 'a')`? This means that a failed validation returns execution without deleting the temporary files. This _might_ cause re-use of the temporary files, especially with the Append. By the way, there is no need to name the temporary files based on a timestamp since it is deleted later.

Comment: Also, why is it writing data to `filename_csv` when it simply reads it back again immediately afterwards? Is it to get some advantage from the CSVReader, or perhaps conversion between `utf-8` and `utf-8-sig`? Also FYI, instead of using `get_object()` and then opening and writing a temp file, the code could simply use `download_file()` to save the file to the temp directory. I realise that these questions are not necessarily providing an answer to your "why is it not working?" question, but these activities do add complexity to the code, which _might_ be causing some of your issues.

Comment: Ah! Realised something else... The initialization of the variables (eg `updateTime`, `timestamp`) is being done _before_ the `lambda_handler()` function is defined. This means that the values are assigned **only once**, when the Lambda container is first created. They are _not_ updated in future executions of the function since they are outside the handler function. This means that the filenames will be re-used (since they never change). Combined with append operation from `open(filename_csv, 'a')`, it means that the previous content is being retained for future executions. Is that intended?

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your comments- they were really useful. It turns out fixing the "The initialization of the variables (eg updateTime, timestamp) is being done before the lambda_handler() function is defined." part fixed everything for me. From your other comments I can see here are glaring inefficiencies in my code that needs fixed, but your last comment got me over the line so the rest is nice to have, I can take my time to go through them and understand what is wrong and how to clean it up.
Again,I appreciate you taking the time to reply, it was a bit of a lifesaver.